# Suppose that a particle is located at the origin $(s = 0)$ at time $t = 1$ and moves along the line with velocity $v(t) = t^{-2}$.

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

**Suppose that a particle is located at the origin $(s = 0)$ at time $t = 1$ and moves along the line with velocity $v(t) = t^{-2}$.**

How can I find the position s as a function of time?

And how can I show that the particle will never cross the point at $s = 2$?

Comment: Hi. Could you please a write a little more about where your attempts so far have lead you, and what sort of a roadblock you are at? This is not a homework website, so its always good to show all your effort!

Comment: @user89 I'm actually trying to learn calculus on my own free time, and I am not sure where to begin. I've never seen a problem like this before.

Comment: $s(t)=\int v(t) dt $ where $s(1)=0$

Comment: That's totally cool! No worries about not being sure about where to begin, but it is important that you learn how to proceed regardless, by trying to identify potential starting points. What are your guesses? Try to guess based on what you have learned so far. As a guide, I'd suggest trying to explore "what is the relationship between velocity and position"?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Something that I wish someone had told me when I started trying to learn calc on my own is how important it is to learn the relationships between position, velocity, and acceleration, and how the areas/tangent lines relate them all. Although these concepts don't inherently involve calculus, they help you understand the uses of the two fundamental operations of elementary calculus: finding the slope of a tangent and the area under a curve. [This video](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/one-dimensional-motion/acceleration_tutorial/v/why-distance-is-area-under-velocity-time-line) is *extremely* instructive in conveying these ideas. Once you get that concept, you can start to realize how powerful the two major tools (the integral and the derivative) are.

Once you understand that, I would then try and go about doing this problem. However, if you just want to know calc to impress your friends/teachers/parents (been there), the integral of the velocity function gives you the position function.